# Distributing a mobile app in-house

Tags: ios, mobile

I've read a some articles about the different ways to distribute an app among employees after subscribing to the Apple Enterprise developer account.I'm interested in the in-house solution.

My question is: How do we distribute the app among the users, I mean with a link, QR code or something else ? Do we have by any way to take control of the targeted device ?

Thank you for your time and attention !

Comment: Have you heard about TestFlight by Apple https://appsto.re/us/W4wM1.i . Could be a possible solution.

Comment: Isn't that for beta testing only ? Thanks